# How To Specify Entities Name for small places?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working with Dialogflow for few months, and trying to explore it by doing a small project. But I am stuck in one problem. In my project there is sentences like : "How many vehicles are there for `place A` to `place B` after `7:40pm` `today` ".

In which :
place A, place B, 7:40pm , today are entities.

`I could not justify what should be the entity type for the places (i.e place A, place B) as others are likely sys.time and sys.date`

I have already tried using sys.location, sys.place, sys.address, but it failed for any new places.

I would be very helpful if you help me to figure out `how to` train those Agents with `place identification`. Or make me correct if I am going somewhere wrong.

And at most, `how many (appox.) training phrases` should be good to train such agent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same type of issue for another entity, I find the best solution **by** **inheriting system entity to our custom entity**.

for example,

The system entity `@sys.location` has limited numbers of location name stored in it. I recommend you to create a new Entity extending the @sys.location and then add all other names that are not recognized.

You can do it by following these steps:

1. First, create an Entity
2. Uncheck the `Define synonyms` checkbox
3. Enter a value `@sys.location:location`
4. Then enter all the names you want to be recognized (i.e. Place A, Place B, etc...).
5. Click save
6. Then go to Intent
7. On Action and parameters, change the `@sys.location` to `@your_entity_name` (the name of your created entity)
8. Click save

Initially, this approach might not work as expected but if you train your entity by the time with the new places, eventually it will be able to handle all the inputs.

Comment: Thanx a lot..I am going to try this, but what if someone writes the places name in short form, or with dot (.) in between??

Comment: Hi... I have tried what you said... but now it is giving me an empty value inside the parameters

Comment: If it's giving an empty value in a parameter then it's not understanding it.. you might need to train it more